# How to send messages properly from python server to c++ client?

Tags: python, c++, sockets

I have a python server running on the following code:

```
import socket
ss=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ss.bind(('0.0.0.0',8080))
ss.listen(5)
cs,adr=ss.accept()
print("Got a connection from:"+str(adr))
while 1:
    msg=input('Enter your message:')
    cs.send(msg.encode('ascii'))
cs.close()
```

For client I'm using C++.
***client.h:***

```
#include<WinSock2.h>
#include<WS2tcpip.h>
#include<iostream>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
class client {
private:
    const char* IP;
    int PORT;
    SOCKET sock;
public:
    client(char* ip, int port){
        IP = ip;
        PORT = port;
    }
    void createSession();//Creates socket and connects with the server.
    void sendData(char* message);//Sends message to the server, it works fine
    char* receive()
    {
        char message[2000];
        if (recv(sock, message, 2000, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            WSACleanup();
            return (char*)"Failed to receive Message";
        }
        return message;
    }
};
```

***client.cpp:***

```
#include"client.h"
#include<iostream>
#define IP "127.0.0.1"
#define port 8080
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    client c1((char*)IP, port);
    c1.createSession();
    while (1)
    {
        char* message;
        message = c1.receive();
        cout << IP << ':' << port << " Says: " << message << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but the message that I'm receiving is garbage. I'm guessing it's a conversion error because for python clients, I'd use `recv(length).decode('ascii')` to decode the message first when receiving. How do I fix this?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but every time you feel the need to do a C-style cast (like you do with `(char*)IP`) you should take that as a sign that you do something wrong. Why aren't you using `std::string` for all your strings in C++?

Comment: More related to your problems, why don't you show the `createSession` or `sendData` functions? Please [edit] your question to include a proper [mre]. Also possibly related, the `receive` function returns a pointer to a *local* variable. The life-time of the variable `message` (in the `receive` function) will end immediately as the function returns, making the returned pointer invalid. Again: Solve using `std::string`.

Comment: Also remember to *use* the value that `recv` return, so you can properly null-terminate the string you receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char* receive()
{
    char message[2000];
    if (recv(sock, message, 2000, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        WSACleanup();
        return (char*)"Failed to receive Message";
    }
    return message;
}
...
message = c1.receive();
cout << IP << ':' << port << " Says: " << message << endl;
```

This is wrong in multiple places:

- You are reading the data into a buffer allocated on the function stack (`message[2000]`). This buffer will be automatically freed after the functions exits, so what you return from the function is no longer there.
- When printing you treat the message as a `\0`-terminated char[] even though its not `\0` terminated. This means that garbage after the received message will be printed though, until a `\0` gets found. It might well be that no `\0` gets found within the buffer in which case it will continue to read, possibly outside allocated memory and thus crash.
- You assume that the `send` in Python will send the full message but this is not guaranteed. Check the return value of `send` on how much was actually send or use `sendall`.
- You assume that `recv` in C will receive the full message but this is not guaranteed. TCP has no concept of a message and `recv` will return just return the bytes already received. Especially with large messages or small TCP windows this might not be the complete message you intended.